# How to execute multiple sql files in postgreSQL linux?

Tags: command-line, postgresql-9.1, sql-scripts

I have many .sql files in a folder (/home/myHSH/scripts) in linux debian. I want to know the command to execute or run all sql files inside the folder into postgreSQL v9.1 database.

PostgreSQL informations:

```
Database name=coolDB
User name=coolUser
```

Nice to have: if you know how to execute multiple sql files through GUI tools too like pgAdmin3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From your command line, assuming you're using either Bash or ZSH (in short, anything but csh/tcsh):

```
for f in *.sql;
do
    psql coolDB coolUser -f "$f"
done
```

Comment: I find this answer to be a much better option as it runs the files in alphanumerical order. So if you have files that are dependent on the order this will handle it correctly whereas xargs will run them any order.

Answer (score 5):

The `find` command combined with `-exec` or `xargs` can make this really easy.

If you want to execute `psql` once per file, you can use the `exec` command like this

```
find . -iname "*.sql" -exec psql -U username -d databasename -q -f {} \;
```

`-exec` will execute the command once per result.

The `psql` command allows you to specify multiple files by calling each file with a new `-f` argument. e.g. you could build a command such as

```
psql -U username -d databasename -q -f file1 -f file2
```

This can be accomplished by piping the result of the `find` to an `xargs` command once to format the files with the -f argument and then again to execute the command itself.

```
find . -iname "*.sql" | xargs printf -- ' -f %s' | xargs -t psql -U username -d databasename -q
```

Comment: with multiple -f attribute, psql takes a single connection or multiple connections proportionate to -f count?  if proportionate, will be parallel?